# Logrotate without Admin or sudo Access - linux

Tags: linux, logrotate

I don't have logrotate installed in my linux,

I need to use logrotate in my local without having sudo permissions or root permissions.

Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: Off topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I tried using logrotate as a package, but it didnt workout, if i install without sudo permissions, it throw's so many errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html) instead.

Comment: Even that is not installed, kindly suggest an alternate